# Django Prepopulated Fields with two/three letter words

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my admin.py file I am trying to use Prepopulated_fields to auto slug a title. It seems to have problems with short two letter words however. When I type in "Is", "the" or "to", it blanks it out of the slug. Also I tried "before" and the second I hit the E button, it blanked that out too. Is this expected with prepopulated fields or am I doing something wrong?

Models.py

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
entry = models.TextField()    
date_edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name = "Last edited")
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Post Date")
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Admin.py

```
 prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Alasdair said in his answer, there are words that get ignored when you use prepoulated_fields. Instead of overriding the js file that handles those words I turned the slug field from the title in the save_model.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):        
    if not change:
        obj.slug = slugify(('%s') % obj.title)
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `prepopulated_fields` option correctly. If you look at the [urlify.js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/urlify.js) script included in the django admin app, you can see there's a list of words which are ignored.

I'm not aware of an easy way to modify the behaviour besides editing the file itself, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the link. I wonder why the remove those words?

Comment: @Austin they're assuming that there will be other, much more interesting words, so they might as well focus on those in order to create the most meaningful 50 character slug possible. "Is the meaning of life important in and of itself: a professor of philosophy ponders" becomes "is-the-meaning-of-life-important-in-and-of-itself" vs "meaning-life-important-itself-professor-philosophy". You could argue the second communicates more information.

Comment: But at the same time it can change the meaning of some things, e.g. "Assistant to the Regional Manager" becomes "assistant-regional-manager".