# Why slug does not include 'is' word?

Tags: django, django-admin

Hi I use SlugField in my model. And I `prepopulated` it with `title`. It works well in admin interface except for `is` word. Why dont slug include that word. I could not understand. For example when I write`My name is Maksim`, it gives me `my-name-maksim`

Comment: I tryied to put `i\s` escape character it worked well but is there any options

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835710/django-prepopulated-fields-with-two-three-letter-words